# How class observable (obs) using Getx in flutter

Tags: flutter, observable, state, flutter-getx, state-management

This is issue,

`final Rx<MainGetHomeElementsModel?> mainModel =Rx<MainGetHomeElementsModel?[].obs;`

observable class in getx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue using this idea,

```
  final Rx<HomeModel?> mainModel =HomeModel(content: []).obs;

  final Rx<HomeModel?> mainModel=Rxn<HomeModel>() ;
```